# change the value of the key in the current array object react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a steate with an array of objects:

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState([
   { value1: false, value2: false, value3: false },
   { value1: false, value2: false, value3: false },
   { value1: false, value2: false, value3: false }
]);
```

And using the `map` method, I render a div for each object:

```
{Value.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={i}
        onClick={() => {
          setValue((oldArr) => {
            let newArr = [...oldArr];
            newArr[i].value3 = true;
            return newArr;
          });
        }}
      >
        {item.value3 ? 'yes' : 'no'}
      </div>
    );
})}
```

And then I click to assign the `true` to the key `value3` of the current object.

But I can't figure out how I should assign the `false` to all other keys `value3` from other objects on this click. Exactly, I want to click and get `true` for current key `value3` and all **other** `value3` get `false`.

Help me pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, this is mutating state:

```
newArr[i].value3 = true;
```

Definitely don't do that.  We can solve both this and the issue at hand by projecting these array elements into a new array, setting other values to `false` and the target value to `true`.  For example:

```
setValue((oldArr) => oldArr.map((a, x) => ({
  ...a,
  value3: x === i ? true : false
}));
```

What this does is map over the existing array, constructing new objects which contain all properties of the existing objects and a manual value for `value3`, which is `true` if the index of the array matches `i` and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by first updating all the value3 properties to false in the onClick handler, and then setting the value3 of the clicked item to true. Here's how you can modify your onClick handler:-

```
onClick={() => {
  setValue((oldArr) => {
    let newArr = oldArr.map((item, index) => {
      return {
        ...item,
        value3: index === i ? true : false
      };
    });
    return newArr;
  });
}}
```